# In React-Native, Cubejs-client/core package is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, node-modules, analytics, cube

Actually, I'm using React native version 0.71 for building an analytics app, so I'm using cubejs for that.

I am following the cubejs official blogs of React-native to create a dashboard

https://cube.dev/blog/react-native-charts-with-cubejs-victory

I have done exactly the same as in the blog, But still I am getting the problem which is, when I import the package of @cubejs-client/core and @cubejs-client/react the screen becomes blank and hangs and the Maximum call stack size is exceeded and some internal recursion is going on

I had found the issue by doing the full stack trace by debugging in Android studio ,
it shows this error

```
     │ TypeError: An error was thrown when attempting to render log messages via LogBox.
                 │ 
                 │ undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
                 │ RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth), js engine: hermes
                 │ TypeError: An error was thrown when attempting to render log messages via LogBox.
                 │ 
                 └ undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
```

So I didn't got anything about which module is crashing or leading to recursion

Currently i have used version of 0.33.12 of these packages(@cubejs-client/core and @cubejs-client/react )

And by disabling the hermes of React it gives errors like this

```
$$\_REQUIRE(dependencyMap\[2\], "../internals/is-constructor") is not a function. (In '$$\_REQUIRE(dependencyMap\[2\], "../internals/is-constructor")(C)', '$$\_REQUIRE(\_dependencyMap\[2\], "../internals/is-constructor")' is an instance of Object)
```

I also searched this issue but didnt got anything relevant to tackle this issue-

I have tried and switched to many versions of React Native and also used lower and older versions of cubejs packages, but still, I got the same error
this is the screenshot of that issue screen is blank and hangs while importing the package of cubejs

```
      import cubejs from '@cubejs-client/core';
      import {CubeProvider} from '@cubejs-client/react';
```

Screenshot_2023-06-21-18-44-23-207_com analyticsapp

According to me the package of @cubejs-client/core and @cubejs-client/react is not compatible with React-Native versions

So Actually I want to give some ways to integrate or make the package of @cubejs-client/core and @cubejs-client/react so that it will be compatible to React-native

Version:

React Native version 0.71

@cubejs-client/core 0.33.12

@cubejs-client/react 0.33.12

I want some alternative way to integrate cubejs packages in react-native